# Why the tuple type can not be inferred in the list recursion?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, recursion, type-inference, tuples

I want to refine the raw text by using regular expression, given a list of (patten,replacement) tuple.

I tried to use the patten matching on the list element but failed, the error showed that "This expression was expected to have type string * string list but here has type 'a list".

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

Codes are as follows:

```
let rec refine (raw:string) (rules:string*string list) = 
    match rules with
    | (pattern,replacement) :: rest ->
        refine <| Regex.Replace(raw,pattern,replacement) rest
    | [] -> raw
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `string * string list` is a pair consisting of a string and a list of strings, whereas you want a `(string * string) list`:

```
let rec refine (raw:string) (rules:(string*string) list) =
    match rules with
    | (pattern,replacement) :: rest ->
        refine (Regex.Replace(raw,pattern,replacement)) rest
    | [] -> raw
```

Alternatively, the only reason you need that particular annotation is because `Regex.Replace` is overloaded.  This is why your other solution works, but there are other (more minimal) places you can put an annotation that will work:

```
let rec refine (raw:string) rules =
    match rules with
    | (pattern,replacement:string) :: rest ->
        refine (Regex.Replace(raw,pattern,replacement)) rest
    | [] -> raw
```

Comment: Cool, I prefer your second solution and the F# can accomplish type-inference from Regex.Replace parameter list. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works when I try this:

```
let rec refine (raw:string) rules = 
    match rules with
    | rule :: rest ->
        //get tuple values beyond the patten matching
        let (pattern:string,replacement:string) = rule 
        refine (Regex.Replace(raw,pattern,replacement)) rest
    | [] -> raw
```